# rx java obsever pojo model for change

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

how use detect change POJO model?
see sample

```
public class User {
     String firstName;
     String latsName;
}
```

and

```
public void main(){
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName("rasoul");

    //detect change by rxJava or Rx android

}
```

I need use rxjava to detect change model user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your model be observable for changes.

```
public class User {
     public interface ChangeListener {
         void onChanged(User user);
     }

     private List<ChangeListener> changeListeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

     public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
         this.changeListeners.add(listener);
     }

     public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
         this.changeListeners.remove(listener);
     }

     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;

     public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
         this.firstName = firstName;
         for(ChangeListener changeListener: changeListeners) {
             changeListener.onChanged(this);
         }
     }
}
```

Because now you can observe a user:

```
user.addChangeListener((u) -> {
    // user changed
});
```

And now you can easily wrap it as observable:

```
public class RxUser {
    private RxUser() {}

    public static Observable<User> observe(final User user) {
        return Observable.create((emitter) -> {
              final User.ChangeListener changeListener = (user) -> {
                  emitter.onNext(user);
              }

              emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromAction(() -> { user.removeChangeListener(listener); }));

              user.addChangeListener(listener);
        });
    }
```

And now you can do

```
User u = new User();
Disposable disposable = RxUser.observe(u).subscribe((user) -> {
    // will be called for changes
});

u.setFirstName("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use a subject. You could expose the underlying `Observer` of your `Subject` and subscribe to it. To notify changes of your data, just call `Subject.onNext`, all the subscribers will receive the updated data.

You can read more about [Subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)t(s) here